# I need to had a calendar with dates marked in different colors mentioning different events. How can I achieve this in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to have a calendar with dates marked in different colors mentioning different events. How can I achieve this in angular2?

Comment: Can you please show what have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks Vinod.I tried doing it using Angular2 Calendar, but I am unable to change background of eventdate with it.

Answer (score 1):

If its Angular 2 and you have no issues with using a 3rd party package then you can go for angular-calendar available on npm. It has the features for showing event based data in a calendar and many other features including the one for the color that you need. For more description, demo and implementation please follow the following link 
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Comment: Thanks Amit for your suggestion. I will try it.